# How to define my own mapping between java to database Object

Tags: java, hibernate, orm

Is these some Way to define my own mapping of hibernate to database Object??
For example, by default String maps to varchar(45), I want to change it to TEXT or just varchar(245) , what are the ways of achieving it ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use either

```
<property name="description" type="string">
    <column name="description" length="100" />
</property>
```

in **xml** or

```
@Column(name="description", length=100)
```

annotation in **class**.

Alternatively, you can use `@Type` annotation - for more info see [this](http://java.dzone.com/articles/annotating-custom-types) or [this](http://docs.jboss.org/ejb3/app-server/HibernateAnnotations/reference/en/html_single/).

You probably want to use `@Type(type="text")`.

Comment: I too searched on net ...somehow not able to reach right place ... wrong search supposigly ...your link is perfect .... thanks a ton ..